# How would I create a custom list class in python?

Tags: python, list

I would like to write a custom list class in Python (let's call it `MyCollection`) where I can eventually call:

```
for x in myCollectionInstance:
    #do something here
```

How would I go about doing that? Is there some class I have to extend, or are there any functions I must override in order to do so?

Comment: Could you clarify better your requirements? If you subclass any iterable class (list, dict, etc...) it should work without problems. But maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @mac: If I subclassed an iterable class, I'd also want a way to be able to access the underlying list object so that I can provide additional functions that act on it. I don't want a key-value pair (dict), so something that emulates an indexed collection (list) would suffice.

Answer (score 43):

Your can subclass `list` if your collection basically behaves like a list:

```
class MyCollection(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyCollection, self).__init__(args[0])
```

However, if your main wish is that your collection supports the iterator protocol, you just have to provide an `__iter__` method:

```
class MyCollection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]

    def __iter__(self):
        for elem in self._data:
            yield elem
```

This allows you to iterate over any instance of `MyCollection`.

Answer (score 22):

I like to subclass [`MutableSequence`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableSequence), as [recommended by Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3488283/667301).

If you want a fairly comprehensive implementation of a `MutableSequence()` list, you can take a look at the [CPython `collections.UserList()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/208a7e957b812ad3b3733791845447677a704f3e/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1174) source.

I added notes about using an acl... if you want to restrict the list to only holding certain kinds of objects, you can use an acl method to optionally ensure that you're only maintaining certain object types in the `MutableSequence()` subclass.

```py
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

class MyList(MutableSequence):
    """
    An extensive user-defined wrapper around list objects.

    Inspiration:
        https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/208a7e957b812ad3b3733791845447677a704f3e/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1174https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/208a7e957b812ad3b3733791845447677a704f3e/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1174
    """

    def __init__(self, initlist=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = []
        if initlist is not None:
            if isinstance(initlist, list):
                self.data[:] = initlist

            elif isinstance(initlist, MyList):
                self.data[:] = initlist.data[:]

            else:
                self.data = list(initlist)

    def __repr__(self):
        return """<{} data: {}>""".format(self.__class__.__name__, repr(self.data))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.data < self.__cast(other)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.data <= self.__cast(other)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.data == self.__cast(other)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.data > self.__cast(other)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.data >= self.__cast(other)

    def __cast(self, other):
        return other.data if isinstance(other, MyList) else other

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in self.data

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if isinstance(idx, slice):
            return self.__class__(self.data[idx])
        else:
            return self.data[idx]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        # optional: self._acl_check(val)
        self.data[idx] = value

    def __delitem__(self, idx):
        del self.data[idx]

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyList):
            return self.__class__(self.data + other.data)

        elif isinstance(other, type(self.data)):
            return self.__class__(self.data + other)

        return self.__class__(self.data + list(other))

    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyList):
            return self.__class__(other.data + self.data)

        elif isinstance(other, type(self.data)):
            return self.__class__(other + self.data)

        return self.__class__(list(other) + self.data)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyList):
            self.data += other.data

        elif isinstance(other, type(self.data)):
            self.data += other

        else:
            self.data += list(other)

        return self

    def __mul__(self, nn):
        return self.__class__(self.data * nn)

    __rmul__ = __mul__

    def __imul__(self, nn):
        self.data *= nn
        return self

    def __copy__(self):
        inst = self.__class__.__new__(self.__class__)
        inst.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)

        # Create a copy and avoid triggering descriptors
        inst.__dict__["data"] = self.__dict__["data"][:]

        return inst

    def append(self, value):
        self.data.append(value)

    def insert(self, idx, value):
        self.data.insert(idx, value)

    def pop(self, idx=-1):
        return self.data.pop(idx)

    def remove(self, value):
        self.data.remove(value)

    def clear(self):
        self.data.clear()

    def copy(self):
        return self.__class__(self)

    def count(self, value):
        return self.data.count(value)

    def index(self, idx, *args):
        return self.data.index(idx, *args)

    def reverse(self):
        self.data.reverse()

    def sort(self, /, *args, **kwds):
        self.data.sort(*args, **kwds)

    def extend(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyList):
            self.data.extend(other.data)

        else:
            self.data.extend(other)

if __name__=='__main__':
    foo = MyList([1,2,3,4,5])
    foo.append(6)
    print(foo)  # <MyList [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]>

    for idx, ii in enumerate(foo):
        print("MyList[%s] = %s" % (idx, ii))
```

Comment: `if not (data is None):` that's not how you write your python code, until a Grand Jedi Master you are. `if data is not None` -- this looks good.

Comment: True, in addition, I guess only `if data:` should work fine.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3 we have beautiful `collections.UserList([list])`:

> Class that simulates a list. The instance’s contents are kept in a
>   regular list, which is accessible via the data attribute of UserList
>   instances. The instance’s contents are initially set to a copy of
>   list, defaulting to the empty list `[]`. list can be any iterable, for
>   example a real Python list or a UserList object.
>
> In addition to supporting the methods and operations of mutable
>   sequences, UserList instances provide the following attribute: `data`
>   A real list object used to store the contents of the UserList class.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userlist-objects

Answer (score 4):

You could extend the `list` class:

```
class MyList(list):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyList, self).__init__(args[0])
        # Do something with the other args (and potentially kwars)
```

Example usage:

```
a = MyList((1,2,3), 35, 22)
print(a)
for x in a:
    print(x)
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Implementing a *list* from scratch requires you to implement
the [full container protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types):

```
__len__()

__iter__()    __reversed__()

_getitem__()  __contains__()
__setitem__() __delitem__()

__eq__()      __ne__()       __gt__()
__lt__()      __ge__()       __le__()

__add__()     __radd__()     __iadd__()
__mul__()     __rmul__()     __imul__()

__str__()     __repr__()     __hash__
```

But the crux of the *list* is its *read-only* protocol,
as captured by [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence)'s 3 methods:

- `__len__()`
- `__getitem__()`
- `__iter__()`

To see that in action, here it is a *lazy* read-only list backed
by a [`range` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range)
(super handy because it knows how to do *slicing gymnastics*),
where any materialized values are stored in a cache (e.g. a dictionary):

```py
import copy
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import Dict, Union

class LazyListView(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, length):
        self._range = range(length)
        self._cache: Dict[int, Value] = {}

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._range)

    def __getitem__(self, ix: Union[int, slice]) -> Value:
        length = len(self)

        if isinstance(ix, slice):
            clone = copy.copy(self)
            clone._range = self._range[slice(*ix.indices(length))]  # slicing
            return clone
        else:
            if ix < 0:
                ix += len(self)  # negative indices count from the end
            if not (0 <= ix < length):
                raise IndexError(f"list index {ix} out of range [0, {length})")
            if ix not in self._cache:
                ...  # update cache
            return self._cache[ix]

    def __iter__(self) -> dict:
        for i, _row_ix in enumerate(self._range):
            yield self[i]
```

Although the above class is still missing the *write-protocol* and all the rest methods
like `__eq__()`, `__add__()`, it is already quite functional.

```py
>>> alist = LazyListView(12)
>>> type(alist[3:])
LazyListView
```

A nice thing is that slices retain the class, so they refrain breaking laziness
and materialize elements (e.g. by coding an appropriate `repr()` method).

Yet the class still fails miserably in simple tests:

```py
>>> alist == alist[:]
False
```

You have to implement `__eq__()` to fix this, and use facilities like
[`functools.total_ordering()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.total_ordering)
to implement `__gt__()` etc:

```py
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class LaxyListView
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self is other:
            return True
        if len(self) != len(other):
            return False
        return all(a == b for a, b in zip(self, other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self is other:
            return 0
        res = all(self < other for a, b in zip(self, other)
        if res:
            return len(self) < len(other)
```

But that is indeed considerable effort.

NOTICE: if you try to bypass the effort and inherit `list` (instead of `Sequence`),
more modifications are needed because, e.g. `copy.copy()` would now try to copy also
the underlying *list* and end up calling `__iter__()`, destroying laziness;
furthermore,  `__add__()`  method fills-in internally list, breaking adding of slices.